# Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size

Tags: java, minecraft

Im trying to start a .jar file with these args:

```
"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-16.0.2.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -Xmx4G -Xms3G -jar paper.jar
```

and I get the error:

````
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size```
````

Comment: it's using the preset value. Check the value set with `echo %_JAVA_OPTIONS%` and set it in Environment variables or perhaps delete it altogether.

Comment: @karakfa, how do I keep those variables but ignore them here specifically?

Comment: I'm using macOS, but **maybe** it works with Windows, too: In Linux and macOS you can execute `_JAVA_OPTIONS=... java -jar ...` to set the options for a specific process at the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the current JAVA_OPTS value

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```

I am suggesting to keep on rate 1 to 2 between Xms and Xmx

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable.